# Homogeneous polynomials on $\mathbb{P}^5$ which vanish on $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have the following questions, both of which has been claimed/used in Fulton and Harris's Representation Theory book.

Suppose $\mathbb{P}^2$ sits inside $\mathbb{P}^5$ via the [Veronese map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronese_surface) (both are complex projective spaces).

How does one show that the quadratic polynomials over $\mathbb{P}^5$ which vanish on $\mathbb{P}^2$ is isomorphic to the projective space associated to $\operatorname{Sym}^2(V^*)$, where $V=\mathbb{C}^3$? Fulton-Harris gives some geometric argument (page 190, see the paragraph before exercise 13.13) but I am unable to get it. I would like to get a very explicit bijection between the two sets.

Can we describe the space of cubic polynomials over $\mathbb{P}^5$ which vanish on $\mathbb{P}^2$? How to compute the dimension of this space? (this has been used in Fulton-Harris to prove the equation 13.15, page 191) [this was asked in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470692/dimension-of-the-space-of-cubic-polynomials-over-mathbbp5-which-vanish-on), but did not get a satisfactory answer].

In general, how to compute the dimension of the space of homogeneous polynomials of a given degree over $\mathbb{P}^5$ which vanish on $\mathbb{P}^2$? Is there an algorithm for such thing?

Approaches which use elementary algebraic geometry is more preferable since I am not much familiar with advanced stuffs.

Comment: What you you mean when you write "this was asked in MSE, but did not get a satisfactory answer"?  It appears that the question was answered on MSE.

Comment: In MSE the answer provides a code (which I am not aware) that computes the dimension, the answer does not satisfy me because it does not explain the algorithm that has been used in the code (as I commented there).

Comment: Perhaps, then, you should ask a question about using Macaulay2.